# A problem with the Telegram app- online status

Tags: iphone

I have a problem with my device and it would be great if anyone can help me with this problem.

In Telegram Messenger app; when I close the App, either by closing it or by coming out from the app my "ONLINE" is on just temporarily.

If I check my status from another device in front of my name is still written ONLINE.

Is there a way to change this On-line reporting to be more accurate.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Previous versions of [Telegram](https://telegram.org) used to linger on changing one's status from `online` to `last seen just now` for about 5-10 minutes. (Not documented, just my observation.) But I think they've fixed this in the latest version. Please update Telegram on all your devices and check if this problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the other device that shows your online status, If you sync the device it will show your status online.